How to create a getch in vlang?
I making a brainfuck interpreter and "," require to get a char without enter but I vlang their is not such of function like getch, the input_character
I have tried embeding C code in Vlang and use C2V but it failed.
I expecting that user press any key don't require to press enter, the function return a keyboard scancode

I found out I will create a ncurses wapper for vlang

Note that brainfuck does not require this; the ',' command gets the next byte of input but it's fine if the input is line-buffered so that input is not available until the user has hit enter to send the whole line. In that case the ',' command will implicitly pause the program until enter is hit, and then return the first byte of the line and continue; this is the most common behavior of brainfuck implementations when reading from a keyboard, and fully legitimate.

Indeed, there are functions in Vlang's default modules like 'builtin' such as:
fn input_character() int

However, this function requires pressing the Enter key to operate.
'getch()', are not part of the standard C library ( unlike getchar() ).
You need to use 'conio' or its equivalent on Linux, such as 'ncurses', to achieve what you are looking for.
To provide a minimalist example of code in Vlang on Linux systems, it would look like this:
#flag linux -I/usr/include/ncurses
#flag linux -lncurses
#include "ncurses.h"

fn C.initscr() ?
fn C.cbreak()
fn C.noecho()
fn C.getch() int
fn C.endwin() int

fn main() {
    C.initscr()
    C.cbreak()
    C.noecho()

    char_ := C.getch()

    C.endwin()

    println('Character read: ${char_.str()}')
}

To explain the code a bit, we import the ncurses library and declare the functions from the library so that they can be used in Vlang code. Finally, we use them in the main function.
You can read the official documentation to understand how to use C code with V code.
I also recommend reading the documentation of the different libraries such as conio or ncurses to achieve the desired result.

==================
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
...
(Use v -cg to print the entire error message)
builder error:
C error found. It should never happen, when compiling pure V code.
This is a V compiler bug, please report it using v bug file.v,
or goto https://github.com/vlang/v/issues/new/choose .
You can also use #help on Discord: https://discord.gg/vlang .

Small fix for macos
#flag -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.5/include/
#flag -lncurses
#include <ncurses.h>
fn C.getch() int
fn C.initscr() ?
fn C.endwin() int
fn C.cbreak()
fn C.noecho()
fn main() {
C.initscr()
C.cbreak()
C.noecho()
    c := C.getch()
    C.endwin()
    println(c)

}

The code I provided was an example for use on Linux. You will need to adapt the includes and libraries according to the OS you are using or targeting. However, the basic idea of the code remains the same and will be useful to write a wrapper.
